# For $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}), g(x) = \int_x^{x+1}f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ show $\lim_{x \to\infty} g(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question on an old exam I'm studying from and I'm not really sure how to approach it.

$f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(t)\mathrm{d}t} < \infty$.  I'm guessing the argument is something along the lines of "as $x \rightarrow \infty, \int f^2(t)\mathrm{d}t \rightarrow 0$ so $\int 0 = 0$, but I'm not entirely sure how to show that.  Is it because it is the infinite integral of a positive number going to zero the integrand must go to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_{n}:\mathbb{R\rightarrow\mathbb{R}}$
by $f_{n}(t)=f(t)1_{[-n,n]}(t)$. Clearly $f_{n}\in L^{2}$. Moreover,
$(f_{n}-f)^{2}\rightarrow0$ pointwisely. Note that $(f_{n}-f)^{2}\leq f^{2}$
and $f^{2}$ is integrable. By the dominated convergence theorem,
we have that $\lim_{n}\int(f_{n}-f)^{2}dm=0$. That is, $||f_{n}-f||_{2}\rightarrow0$.
For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $1_{[x,x+1]}\in L^{2}$. By Cauchy-Schwarz
inequality, $f1_{[x,x+1]}\in L^{1}$ and $\int|f1_{[x,x+1]}|dm\leq||f||_{2}||1_{[x,x+1}||_{2}<\infty$.
This shows that $g(x)=\int f1_{[x,x+1]}dm$ is well-defined. Now,
we go to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $n$ such that $||f_{n}-f||_{2}<\varepsilon$.
For any $x>n$, observe that $f_{n}1_{[x,x+1]}=0$, so $\int f_{n}1_{[x,x+1]}dm=0$.
Now, for any $x>n$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |g(x)|\\
 & = & |\int f1_{[x,x+1]}dm|\\
 & = & |\int f1_{[x,x+1]}dm-\int f_{n}1_{[x,x+1]}dm|\\
 & \leq & \int|f-f_{n}|1_{[x,x+1]}dm\\
 & \leq & ||f-f_{n}||_{2}\cdot||1_{[x,x+1]}||_{2}\\
 & = & ||f-f_{n}||_{2}\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=0$.

Comment: Here, $m$ stands for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.